# Adobe content server

Tags: adobe, drm

I am interested in buying an Adobe Content Server to protect my digital products over my Online store but before that I want to make sure everything as they are asking a huge investment.

How they will implement this whole scenario? I mean on their server and my server will be calling them again and again or it will be implemented on my server only?

Please share your important experience.

thanks,
Pras

Answer (score 0):

Content server wil be installed on your server. You will be responsible for packaging the files, encrypting it, delivering it to the distributors. Only the Signing of the file will be done by adobe server(intermediate step in packaging).

Along with authentication of user and other stuff will be managed by adobe server. Every thing else will be on your server.

I too am in process of implementing it. Need any help or query. Contact me (9235556759)

Siddharth